# python is the constructor in this singletone called each time Although i can see it only once in __init(self)__?

Tags: python, singleton

i have this singletone im using :

```
class MyThreadSafeSingleton(type):   
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dictionary):
        super(Singleton, cls).__init__(name, bases, dictionary)
        cls._instance = None
        cls._rlock = threading.RLock()
        print("MyThreadSafeSingleton __init__")

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kws):
        with cls._rlock:
            if cls._instance is None:
                cls._instance = super(MyThreadSafeSingleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kws)
        print("MyThreadSafeSingleton __call__")
        return cls._instance
```

and i have simple class that using it :

```
from utiils.singletone import MyThreadSafeSingleton
class Foo(object, metaclass=MyThreadSafeSingleton):
    def __init__(self):
        self.MyMemeber = 1
        print("Foo __init__")
```

and in main :

```
a = Foo().MyMemeber
b = Foo().MyMemeber
c = Foo().MyMemeber
d = Foo().MyMemeber
```

and the print is :

```
MyThreadSafeSingleton  __init__
Foo __init__
MyThreadSafeSingleton  __call__
MyThreadSafeSingleton  __call__
MyThreadSafeSingleton  __call__
MyThreadSafeSingleton  __call__
```

when i run it in IDE and set break point in

```
 self.MyMemeber = 1
```

i see it enter only once , which leads me to thinking that the constructor called only once .
but what constructor it is calling when i do Foo().MyMemeber ? i mean the "()" part on the Foo
what it triger ?
Thanks

Comment: Isn't the purpose of a Singleton to provide only one instance of an object?

Comment: yes it is , i just wander if i call it right with the () , as i can see in the Class it is called only once . 
so what is this : () ? what do it invoke if any ?

Comment: the class object `Foo` is an instance of `MyThreadSafeSingleton`. When you use the [*a call expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) on `Foo`, it invokes `MyThreadSafeSingelton.__call__`

Comment: By using the parenthesis you are creating an instance of the class Foo. And then you are accessing the value of the attribute `MyMember` and assigning it to a variable

Comment: but also i can see that it return after the first time only ; return cls._instance
from MyThreadSafeSingelton 
it enter in the first time to _call__ init the cls._instance and after that it returns only 
cls._instance

Comment: Yes that's literally the point of using a Singleton. You only create one instance of that object. And that's what your code in the `__call__` method is doing

Comment: yeah i know i just wanted to know if there is some kind of  constructor in the main class 
in python that i call by mistake